# jQuery fadeTo delay in Webkit browsers

Tags: jquery

I've implemented what I feel is a rather simple script on my menu. It works in Firefox and IE, but in Chrome and Safari, there is a delay of about a half-second. All it is doing is setting the opacity 60%, and then 100% on hover.  Here's the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".NavMenu a").fadeTo('200', 0.6);
        $(".NavMenu a").hover(function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('200', 1.0);
        }, function() {
            $(this).fadeTo('200', 0.6); 
        });
    });
```

Has anyone else experienced this, or know of a workaround?  I've tested other sites in Webkit browsers and the fadeTo effect seemed fine.

Thanks for your time.

Patrick

Comment: Can you reproduce this effect with a live [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/), or [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/), demo?

Comment: Interestingly, it works in the demo.  I suppose there must be something conflicting on my page, because the code seems fine.  Here's a link to the demo: http://jsbin.com/aluyi4/3 and here's the webpage, if you're interested:  http://www.boaterexam.com/canada

Comment: strange, have you tried targeting the li instead of the a?

Answer (score 0):

your solution here i think would be to try using animate() instead of fadeTo() like this: 
http://jsbin.com/aluyi4/5/edit also note that you should be setting the initial opacity with css.